# compare and delete elements from lists

Tags: java, logic

i have two lists viz, `addList` and a `deleteList`

the elements in the `addList` are of type `AddEntity` which has two fields

```
- id 
- parentId
```

The AddEntity class is as below

```
public class AddEntity{
    int id;
    int parentId;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

And the entities in the `deleteList` are of type `DeleteEntity` which has only one field

```
- deleteId
```

The DeleteEntity class is as below

```
public class DeleteList{
    int deleteId;
    //gettter and setter for deleteId goes here
}
```

Now I have the two lists
`List<AddEntity> addList`  and  `List<DeleteEntity> deleteList`

For Eg. the `addList` contents are

```
id          parentId

2001          3
2002          2001
2003          2001
2004          2002
2005          2003
2006          4
2007          2006
```

the `deleteList` contents are

```
deleteId

2001
3
2007
```

now i want to delete the all the entities and their children (recursively) from `addList` whose `id/parentId` matches with the `deleteId` of elements in `deleteList`.
and also i want to retain only those entites in `deleteList` which do not match with any of the id in `addList`.

For example, in this case after processing above two lists, the contents of `addList` should be

```
id      parentId

2006    4
```

and `deleteList` would now contain

```
deleteId

3
```

I have got the logic right but facing some problems in the implementations part. I m doing it in JAVA. Hope to find some solutions here.
Thank You!

**EDIT**

-(Because some are upset with the question)

**MY APPROACH**

Actually the logic is very simple. But bit confusing.

```
Step1: For each elements in the deleteList{
        For each elements in the addList{
          a) Match deleteId with id of each element in addList.
             if(deleteId==id){
               mark current element from deleteList for deletion  
               loop:    check if any other element in addList has parentId==id.
                        if YES mark it(addList element) for delete
                        take the id of the marked element and goto "loop"

        }
      }      
Step2: Delete All Marked Elements!!
```

At first I tried to use `foreach` and delete elements from the Lists instead of marking them for delete. This lead to `ConcurrentModificationException`. Then I used Iterator to iterate over the Lists. That is where I got stuck and posetd this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Here I am posting my whole code, But I tested for several scenario only. All comments are welcome.

AddList Class

```
public class AddList {
private int id;
private int parentId;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}

public void setParentId(int parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}
}
```

DeleteList Class

```
public class DeleteList {
private  int deleteId;

public int getDeleteId() {
    return deleteId;
}

public void setDeleteId(int deleteId) {
    this.deleteId = deleteId;
}
}
```

Here is the Main Class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<AddList> addList = new ArrayList<AddList>();
    List<DeleteList> delList = new ArrayList<DeleteList>();
    AddList addL1 = new AddList();
    AddList addL2 = new AddList();
    AddList addL3 = new AddList();
    AddList addL4 = new AddList();
    AddList addL5 = new AddList();
    AddList addL6 = new AddList();
    AddList addL7 = new AddList();

    DeleteList delL1 = new DeleteList();
    DeleteList delL2 = new DeleteList();
    DeleteList delL3 = new DeleteList();

    addL1.setId(2001);
    addL1.setParentId(3);
    addL2.setId(2002);
    addL2.setParentId(2001);
    addL3.setId(2003);
    addL3.setParentId(2001);
    addL4.setId(2004);
    addL4.setParentId(2002);
    addL5.setId(2005);
    addL5.setParentId(2003);
    addL6.setId(2006);
    addL6.setParentId(4);
    addL7.setId(2007);
    addL7.setParentId(2006);

    delL1.setDeleteId(2001);
    delL2.setDeleteId(3);
    delL3.setDeleteId(2007);

    addList.add(addL1);
    addList.add(addL2);
    addList.add(addL3);
    addList.add(addL4);
    addList.add(addL5);
    addList.add(addL6);
    addList.add(addL7);

    delList.add(delL1);
    delList.add(delL2);
    delList.add(delL3);

    removeElements(addList, delList);
}

public static void removeElements(List<AddList> add, List<DeleteList> del) {
    boolean status = true;
    int[] temp = new int[del.size()];
    int[] child = new int[add.size()];
    int i = 0;
    while (status) {
        for (int j = 0; j < add.size(); j++) {
            if (del.get(i).getDeleteId() == add.get(j).getId()) {
                add.remove(j);
                temp[i] = del.get(i).getDeleteId();
                j = -1;
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == del.size()) {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    boolean newStatus = true;
    while (newStatus) {
        for (int j = 0; j < add.size(); j++) {
            if (temp[i] == add.get(j).getParentId()) {
                child[k] = add.get(j).getId();
                add.remove(j);
                k++;
                j = -1;
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == del.size()) {
            newStatus = false;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    boolean con = true;
    while (con) {
        for (int j = 0; j < del.size(); j++) {
            if (temp[i] == del.get(j).getDeleteId()) {
                del.remove(j);
                j = -1;
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == temp.length) {
            con = false;
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    boolean cons = true;
    while (cons) {
        for (int j = 0; j < add.size(); j++) {
            if (child[i] == add.get(j).getParentId()) {
                add.remove(j);
                j = -1;
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == child.length) {
            cons = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```